# Issue plotting Seaborn and Matplotlib figures using loop

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I am having some trouble saving a series of two Seaborn violin plots and a normal matplotlib plot which runs each time my code iterates over a loop.

My code is:

```
for symbol in symbol_list:

    <DO SOMETHING - CREATE PANDAS DATAFRAME NAMED "df">

    img = sns.violinplot(x=df['Onside'].dropna().astype(float))
    fig = img.get_figure()
    fig.savefig(symbol+" Onside Violin Plot.png")
    fig.clf()

    sns.violinplot(x=df['Offside'].dropna().astype(float))
    fig = img.get_figure()

    fig.savefig(symbol+" Offside Violin Plot.png")
    fig.clf()


    plt.figure(1)
    plt.subplot(211)
    plt.hist(df['Onside'],bins=50,alpha=0.5,label="Onside")
    plt.hist(df['Offside'],bins=50,alpha=0.5,label="Offside")
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.xlabel("Pips")
    plt.ylabel("Number of Trades")

    plt.subplot(212)
    plt.bar(df.index,df['Offside'],color='r',width=0.5)
    plt.bar(df.index,df['Onside'],color='blue',width=0.5)
    plt.savefig(symbol+'_Onside_Offside')
    plt.plot()
```

It runs correctly on the first iteration through the loop but on the second go around I get the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-269b21e53a2f> in <module>()
    112     img = sns.violinplot(x=df['Onside'].dropna().astype(float))#.figure.savefig(symbol+" Onside Violin Plot.png")
    113     fig = img.get_figure()
--> 114     fig.savefig(symbol+" Onside Violin Plot.png")
    115     fig.clf()
    116 

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in savefig(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1561             self.set_frameon(frameon)
   1562 
-> 1563         self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
   1564 
   1565         if frameon:

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, **kwargs)
   2230                 orientation=orientation,
   2231                 bbox_inches_restore=_bbox_inches_restore,
-> 2232                 **kwargs)
   2233         finally:
   2234             if bbox_inches and restore_bbox:

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
    525 
    526     def print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs):
--> 527         FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
    528         renderer = self.get_renderer()
    529         original_dpi = renderer.dpi

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in draw(self)
    472 
    473         try:
--> 474             self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
    475         finally:
    476             RendererAgg.lock.release()

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     60     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     61         before(artist, renderer)
---> 62         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     63         after(artist, renderer)
     64 

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
   1157         dsu.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
   1158         for zorder, a, func, args in dsu:
-> 1159             func(*args)
   1160 
   1161         renderer.close_group('figure')

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     60     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     61         before(artist, renderer)
---> 62         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     63         after(artist, renderer)
     64 

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2317 
   2318         for zorder, a in dsu:
-> 2319             a.draw(renderer)
   2320 
   2321         renderer.close_group('axes')

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     60     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     61         before(artist, renderer)
---> 62         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     63         after(artist, renderer)
     64 

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in draw(self, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
   1106         renderer.open_group(__name__)
   1107 
-> 1108         ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks(renderer)
   1109         ticklabelBoxes, ticklabelBoxes2 = self._get_tick_bboxes(ticks_to_draw,
   1110                                                                 renderer)

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in _update_ticks(self, renderer)
    949 
    950         interval = self.get_view_interval()
--> 951         tick_tups = [t for t in self.iter_ticks()]
    952         if self._smart_bounds:
    953             # handle inverted limits

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    949 
    950         interval = self.get_view_interval()
--> 951         tick_tups = [t for t in self.iter_ticks()]
    952         if self._smart_bounds:
    953             # handle inverted limits

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in iter_ticks(self)
    892         Iterate through all of the major and minor ticks.
    893         """
--> 894         majorLocs = self.major.locator()
    895         majorTicks = self.get_major_ticks(len(majorLocs))
    896         self.major.formatter.set_locs(majorLocs)

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py in __call__(self)
   1005     def __call__(self):
   1006         'Return the locations of the ticks'
-> 1007         self.refresh()
   1008         return self._locator()
   1009 

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py in refresh(self)
   1025     def refresh(self):
   1026         'Refresh internal information based on current limits.'
-> 1027         dmin, dmax = self.viewlim_to_dt()
   1028         self._locator = self.get_locator(dmin, dmax)
   1029 

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py in viewlim_to_dt(self)
    769             vmin, vmax = vmax, vmin
    770 
--> 771         return num2date(vmin, self.tz), num2date(vmax, self.tz)
    772 
    773     def _get_unit(self):

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py in num2date(x, tz)
    417         tz = _get_rc_timezone()
    418     if not cbook.iterable(x):
--> 419         return _from_ordinalf(x, tz)
    420     else:
    421         x = np.asarray(x)

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py in _from_ordinalf(x, tz)
    269 
    270     ix = int(x)
--> 271     dt = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(ix).replace(tzinfo=UTC)
    272 
    273     remainder = float(x) - ix

ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    305                 pass
    306             else:
--> 307                 return printer(obj)
    308             # Finally look for special method names
    309             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in <lambda>(fig)
    225 
    226     if 'png' in formats:
--> 227         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
    228     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
    229         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
    117 
    118     bytes_io = BytesIO()
--> 119     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    120     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    121     if fmt == 'svg':

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, **kwargs)
   2178                     orientation=orientation,
   2179                     dryrun=True,
-> 2180                     **kwargs)
   2181                 renderer = self.figure._cachedRenderer
   2182                 bbox_inches = self.figure.get_tightbbox(renderer)

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
    525 
    526     def print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs):
--> 527         FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
    528         renderer = self.get_renderer()
    529         original_dpi = renderer.dpi

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in draw(self)
    472 
    473         try:
--> 474             self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
    475         finally:
    476             RendererAgg.lock.release()

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     60     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     61         before(artist, renderer)
---> 62         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     63         after(artist, renderer)
     64 

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
   1157         dsu.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
   1158         for zorder, a, func, args in dsu:
-> 1159             func(*args)
   1160 
   1161         renderer.close_group('figure')

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     60     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     61         before(artist, renderer)
---> 62         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     63         after(artist, renderer)
     64 

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2317 
   2318         for zorder, a in dsu:
-> 2319             a.draw(renderer)
   2320 
   2321         renderer.close_group('axes')

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     60     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     61         before(artist, renderer)
---> 62         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     63         after(artist, renderer)
     64 

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in draw(self, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
   1106         renderer.open_group(__name__)
   1107 
-> 1108         ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks(renderer)
   1109         ticklabelBoxes, ticklabelBoxes2 = self._get_tick_bboxes(ticks_to_draw,
   1110                                                                 renderer)

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in _update_ticks(self, renderer)
    949 
    950         interval = self.get_view_interval()
--> 951         tick_tups = [t for t in self.iter_ticks()]
    952         if self._smart_bounds:
    953             # handle inverted limits

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    949 
    950         interval = self.get_view_interval()
--> 951         tick_tups = [t for t in self.iter_ticks()]
    952         if self._smart_bounds:
    953             # handle inverted limits

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in iter_ticks(self)
    892         Iterate through all of the major and minor ticks.
    893         """
--> 894         majorLocs = self.major.locator()
    895         majorTicks = self.get_major_ticks(len(majorLocs))
    896         self.major.formatter.set_locs(majorLocs)

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py in __call__(self)
   1005     def __call__(self):
   1006         'Return the locations of the ticks'
-> 1007         self.refresh()
   1008         return self._locator()
   1009 

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py in refresh(self)
   1025     def refresh(self):
   1026         'Refresh internal information based on current limits.'
-> 1027         dmin, dmax = self.viewlim_to_dt()
   1028         self._locator = self.get_locator(dmin, dmax)
   1029 

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py in viewlim_to_dt(self)
    769             vmin, vmax = vmax, vmin
    770 
--> 771         return num2date(vmin, self.tz), num2date(vmax, self.tz)
    772 
    773     def _get_unit(self):

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py in num2date(x, tz)
    417         tz = _get_rc_timezone()
    418     if not cbook.iterable(x):
--> 419         return _from_ordinalf(x, tz)
    420     else:
    421         x = np.asarray(x)

C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py in _from_ordinalf(x, tz)
    269 
    270     ix = int(x)
--> 271     dt = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(ix).replace(tzinfo=UTC)
    272 
    273     remainder = float(x) - ix

ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1
```

Could anyone please point out where I am going wrong?

I assume it's seomthing to do with the "plt" figure not being cleared properly and therefore the code is trying to plot two different indices on the x axis of the same figure, hence the "ordinal must be >= 1" error.

Am i in the right ball park?

Comment: Great stuff that worked..thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the figure first thing in the loop, otherwise the new content would be plottet to the old figure from the previous loop step.

So you can add

```
plt.gcf().clf()
```

at the start of the loop.